# IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL: java.io.IOException: Type {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}array is referenced but not defined

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, axis

I am getting **IWAB0399E Error** in generating Java from **WSDL:  java.io.IOException**: Type {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}array is referenced but not defined' while consuming web service using eclipse Juno.

**Tools used**

1. Eclipse 4.2
2. Jboss 4.2
3. Axis 1

Please advice.

Regards,
pise

Answer (score 0):

I have seen very similar problem quite a few times, also i can see you are using Axis.v1 And this could cause the problem. Try using Axis.v2 when doing WSDL2Java. 
PS. Look also at JAX-WS import tool, its quite fast efficient and easy to use and implement ( also regarding dynamic client ) 
You can see JAX-WS [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may remove the  part of the wsdl, responsible for schema definition. This may solve your problem.
Remove this part below:

```
<types>
     [...]
</types>
```